# If two observers pass each other in opposite directions at $.5c$ what would effect on each others clocks be?

Tags: special-relativity, time, reference-frames, observers

Assume an alternate universe with same physical laws as here. In this universe nothing exists except 3 observers, each in a transparent box with a clock. Observer A is travelling at .5c. Observer C is travelling in the opposite direction at .5c. Observer B is at rest.

In the absence of outside landmarks each would feel they were at rest and their clocks were functioning normally. Suppose they pass each other. To A it would appear B had zoomed by at .5c and C at c. To B it would seem A and C had zoomed by at .5c in opposite directions.

Suppose they noted the functioning of each others' clocks as compared to their own in passing, and they met later to compare notes on their observations. What observations would they have concerning clock function? If C shone a light beam ahead of himself, how would it appear to A?

Comment: "To A it would appear B had zoomed by at .5c and C at c" This is wrong. Relativistic velocities don't just add together. A would observe C travelling at 0.8c

Comment: Assuming the three observers synchronise their clocks as they pass each other, they cannot then have *met later to compare notes on their observations* unless at least two of them accelerated to change their inertial frame to match the third observer. This means you have to calculate the effect of the acceleration as well as the effect of the relative speed. The situation is a minor varient of the twin paradox.

Comment: Assuming as you say they accelerate to match third observer in order to meet how does this affect whatever observations were made in passing?

Answer (score 1):

> To A it would appear B had zoomed by at .5c and C at c. To B it would
>   seem A and C had zoomed by at .5c in opposite directions.

According to accepted physical laws in *this* universe, if something travels at *c* according to one observer, it travels at *c* according to *all* observers.

So, it would be impossible for A to observe C with speed *c* and B to observe C with any other speed but *c*.

This is well known in this universe but, evidently, not so much in your alternate universe.

Comment: Actually, pretty much *all* standard cosmological theories involving multiple universes hold the speed of light and the fundamentals of relativity constant across all universes. So that's true in his alternate universe too.

Comment: @Jim, yes it's true but, evidently, not *known*.  :)

Comment: If B is at rest and C is travelling at .5c how then will it appear that C is travelling at C to B? Jim has corrected my notion that A believing himself at rest would observe C at .8c and not c however C's actual velocity is .5c. How will this not be apparent to B?

Comment: What I am trying to find out here is whether A and C passing each other each believing themselves at rest and noting the apparent velocity of the other would see the other's time dilating or whether their actual velocities were the same would see both clocks operating the same and be able to deduce from that their own motion

Comment: It would be easier to deal with a condescending attitude had, at least been given a correct answer

Comment: @victorhiggins, ill-posed questions don't have correct answers.

Comment: Maybe more attention should be given to the question. Obviously an object travelling at c would be observed at c in all frames. This is not the case here but thanks anyway

Comment: @victorhiggins, why should *I* pay more attention to the question?

Answer (score -2):

if A and C are moving at equal velocities 5c then they should meet  B at the same time ,If the stationary object B stands at the mid point of the motion path then A will cut the track to B at 5c and C will do the same so suppose that half the distance is 5 kilos then Then both A will meet B and C after 1/c time ..so the velocity each one will see the other moving towards him will be 5c

Comment: This is not correct